# bq command line for DML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

1) Is there a way to run below update and merge statments from bq command line?

2) if i save this query in a file (update.sql or merge.sql) , can i pass this file as input to bq command and execute.

If we can do any of above , then i can call that though a script in Informatica job and make it a part of ETL jobs for post load processing.

Thanks for the help.
regards,
Sreekanth

UPDATE `cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.DW_ORDER_LINE_I` TGT SET TGT.BILLABLE_FLAG=SRC.BILLABLE_FLAG FROM  `cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.ORDER_LINE_BILLABLE_FLG_VW` SRC WHERE TGT.INTEGRATION_ID=SRC.ORDER_LINE_ID

MERGE `cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.DW_ORDER_LINE_I` TGT USING `cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.ORDER_LINE_BILLABLE_FLG_VW` SRC ON (TGT.INTEGRATION_ID=SRC.ORDER_LINE_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TGT.BILLABLE_FLAG=SRC.BILLABLE_FLAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run DDL queries via command line with [`bq query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query), in the following manner:

`bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'MERGE cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.DW_ORDER_LINE_I TGT USING cloud-dw-poc.PREPARED_LAYER.ORDER_LINE_BILLABLE_FLG_VW SRC ON (TGT.INTEGRATION_ID=SRC.ORDER_LINE_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TGT.BILLABLE_FLAG=SRC.BILLABLE_FLAG'`

If you'd rather pass the query as a file, you can do:

`cat merge.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=false`

Comment: Will it be possible to store this update or merge in Big Query and call them like a job when needed?